# Как пошагово подключить статическую библиотеку в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компоновщик

Пытался найти записи о том, как подключить статическую библиотеку, однако не нашел ни одного пошагового руководства, а если находил - перевод на русский отличен. На сайте Microsoft подключается библиотека в одном решении, однако если библиотека внешняя - ничего не написано.

Пусть есть файлы

- lib.h
- lib.lib

Как их правильно подключить к проекту?

Comment: [Create a C++ console app that references the static library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#CreateAppToRefTheLib) - если библиотека внешняя, то шаг с добавлением reference пропускается.

Comment: @user7860670 Сейчас еще раз попытаюсь. Почему-то до этого не получалось

Comment: @user7860670 Там написано добавить библиотеку в ссылки, однако линкер не видит библиотеку

Comment: Я же написал, что шаг с добавлением ссылки (reference) пропускается. Однако это не означает, что не надо добавлять библиотеку в список для линковки.

Comment: https://ravesli.com/podklyuchenie-i-ispolzovanie-bibliotek-v-visual-studio-2017/ до 5 шага

Comment: `#pragma comment (lib, "path/to/your.lib")` самое простое